# Building to a device in Xcode.. is there an expiry?

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I ask because I installed to a device (by selecting the device from the simulator menu) and everything was working as expected.

However, after a few weeks it stopped working (immediate crash upon opening).

I tried connecting to the internet and running it again.. and that seemed to make it start working again. However the app itself doesn't use any internet connectivity.

Is there some type of expiry Apple sets when installing to a device using this method?

Or could it be related to the Unity framework needing to touch base?

Comment: You can connect device and check the crash logs.

Comment: are you using unpaid apple account for developing the app?

Comment: @MeeranTariq Nope, I have Enterprise license

Comment: What kind of provisioning file did you use, as well. Your account could be full enterprise, but you could have used a temporary provisioning profile.

Comment: there is an expiry: enterprise should be one year, free account is few days.